# How to consume a soap asmx service from angular+8 with xml on it

Tags: asp.net, angular, xml, web-services, soap

this is my call:

```
  var xmlItemAll =
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
      '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
      '<soap:Body>' +
      '<GetDynamicData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
      '<DynQueryID>FILE_ITEMS</DynQueryID>' +
      '<CriteriaName>USN</CriteriaName>' +
      '<CriteriaValue>50101497</CriteriaValue>' +
      '</GetDynamicData>' +
      '</soap:Body>' +
      '</soap:Envelope>';

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    });

    const hdr = { headers: headers, body: xmlItemAll };

    this.http.post('http://someURL:somePORT/FWebService.asmx?op=GetDynamicData', hdr)
      .toPromise()
      .then((result) => {
           console.log(result)
       }
```

i'm receiving this error:

soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Either the service doesn't like the line and expects the message to directly start with the SOAP envelope, or the first character of that line is a non printable character like the [UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Did you copy the SOAP XML from a file by any chance? If so, you might have picked the BOM with it.

Remove the line or delete and rewrite its first characters to try to get rid of a BOM, then make the call again. You don't necessarily need the line if you change your content type to something like the following, so that the server knows it's UTF-8:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
```

Also, use `text/xml` not `application/xml`.

Two other things I would add, would be to:

- remove the `?op=GetDynamicData` parameter from the endpoint just to keep things clear. That's usually needed for testing and information details about an operation on GET and not needed for calling the service on POST.
- you probably also need to add another HTTP header in the form of a [SOAP action](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528), like `SOAPAction: "Some-Value"` otherwise your service might complain about it. The value you add must match the operation you are calling.

Comment: ok. i try this with no luck:
1.- delete the line and write it down as the same... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
2. remove it, an place it in the header as:       'Content-Type': 'text/xml, charset="utf-8"'
3. also change the text/xml  part
4. delete the ?op=GetDynamicData and place it at the header and endup as:

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml, charset="utf-8"',
      SOAPAction: 'op=GetDynamicData',
    });

still having the same error i mention

Comment: also forget to mention that i try that same code in postman and it works like a charm. but i dont know if i forgeting something in the angular request.  theres a parameter on postman where you place this xml as "raw" and "XML" mode... dont know if that as to be included in th http.post

Comment: Look in the Network tab in the browser debugging tools and see how the request is made. Maybe there is something wrong with the request body.

Comment: Looking closer at your call, is the request content set with `body` or `data`? Like `data: xmlItemAll`

Comment: i review the request and seems to be ok. I copy some code and place the data part, don't know if it is data or body. I already change it but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a quote type problem. Use ` instead of ' or escape the double quotes inside the simple quotes like this:
`<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>`

Comment: well actually i try the `  and the '  and the " .... and all single line, and the + version i end up.  but thanks for pointing that out.  :)